# Should Contravariance Allow the Compiler to Infer T=Circle?

Tags: c#, contravariance, compareto

Okay, I've been instructed that due to contravariance the compiler should be able to infer that T=Circle and therefore allow compilation. However, with compiler version 4.0.30319.1 I get the following error:

error CS0311: The type 'Testable.Shape' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Testable.Test.Foo(System.IComparable, T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Testable.Shape' to 'Testable.ICircle'.

The code, however, compiles normally if I implement IComparable on the Circle class. What might be the problem here?

```
using System; 

namespace Testable 
{ 
    public class Test 
    { 
        public static void Main() 
        { 
            Foo(new Circle(), new Circle()); 
        } 

        public static void Foo<T>(IComparable<T> a, T b) where T : ICircle 
        { 
            a.CompareTo(b); 
        } 
    } 

    public interface ICircle 
    { 
    } 

    public class Shape : IComparable<Shape>
    { 
        public Int32 CompareTo(Shape other) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Called CompareTo(Shape)"); 
            return 0; 
        } 
    } 

    public class Circle : Shape, ICircle 
    { 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Circle` implements `IComparable<Shape>`, and so the compiler chooses `Shape` for T. However, `Shape` does not implement `ICircle`, and so you get the error you see.

I suppose that begs the question, though. Why doesn't the compiler revise its guess to `Circle` once it sees the `ICircle` constraint. The answer is that [constraints are not used to aid in type inference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx). They can only *invalidate* a guess after it has been made.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I"ll be sure to read it later tonight. (Exams and all)

Comment: Suppose though that `Circle` were defined in another namespace. The compiler would not be able to 'revise its guess' at the call site of Foo given that new classes could be added later in other namespaces. The 'best guess' may not be available at the time of compilation. We can just give the compiler a hint by specifying the type parameter: `Foo<Circle>(new Circle(), new Circle())`